# button passing javascript variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, button

I am getting this data from a mysql database and printing each line and adding a button. But the escaping is a major issue. Is there a way to easily convert this into DOM instead of printing inline html?

```
render : function(template,params){
var arr = [];
switch(template){
    case 'loginTopBar':
        arr = [
        '<span><img src="',params.gravatar,'" width="23" height="23" />',
        '<span class="name">',params.name,
        '</span><a href="" class="logoutButton rounded">Logout</a></span>'];
    break;



    case 'chatLine':

        arr = [
            '<div class="chat chat-',params.id,' rounded"><span class="gravatar"><img src="',params.gravatar,
            '" width="23" height="23" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" />','</span><span class="author">',params.author,
            ':</span><span class="text">"',params.text,'"</span><span class="time">',params.time,'</span></div>'];
    break;



    case 'user':

        arr = [
            '<div class="user" id="',params.text,'" title="',params.text,'"> <button type="button" value="',params.text,'" class="btn btn-success" onclick="ImageHosting_Click( \'',params.text,'\')"></button>',params.text,'',params.text,'</div>'
        ];
    break;  

    case 'userz':
        arr = [
            '<div class="userz" title="',params.disp,'">',params.disp,'</div><br>'  
        ];
    break;
}

// A single array join is faster than
// multiple concatenations

return arr.join('');
```

},

Comment: `ImageHosting_Click(',params.text,')`  This is going to expand like ->  `imageHosting_Click(hello there)`  so I'm even surprised it would work without spaces., unless you put `"hello"` into the params text.. note the double "..  You can escape some single quotes using `\'`

Comment: Yes I think you are onto something. Need it to read 'hello' inside the function. How can I get that?

Comment: Ideally, you don't want to build your HTML into a string, as it's just going to get more complicated with escaping etc,  eg. what if somebody put double quotes, or single quotes into the params.   Creating the element in the DOM and using the innerText would be better.  But if you do want what you have above to work you can escape a single quote into your string -> `'" class="btn btn-success" onclick="ImageHosting_Click(\''`   Notice the `\''`  2 single quotes, you will need to do this also for the closing bit too.

Comment: can you show me in context of using that ',f,'

Comment: I built it into a string because it is an ajax app refreshing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've escaped the single quotes for you, again notice the `\''` that's the trick.  But be aware there are other escaping issues, like if `f="shoe's"` etc.

And is the reason I suggest creating the DOM element first, and using innerText etc..

```js
var f= "hello";
var arr = ['<button type="button" onclick="ImageHosting_Click(\'',f,'\')">'];

console.log(arr.join(''));
```

Comment: thanks so much. how can I build this into DOM, ive added more context above.

Comment: Just looking at your code now, it looks like it's Node.js, express maybe.  In this case you can't put directly into the DOM this way.  But saying this most templating engines have some built in escaping for HTML entities and you would use that.

Comment: Thanks Keith for the info

Answer (score 0):

Try this it would be work for you

```
<button type="button" onclick="ImageHosting_Click(\'',f,\'')">
```

Comment: will this allow for symbols to come through safely?